# DOM node id after angularjs application loads

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on an AngularJs based application in which there's a Google Map showing some events around your location.
The map has its own DOM id ("#map") that it's used for loading the map's content (markers ecc..)  inside the Map Controller,

I have a structure like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
<div id="map"></div>

</div>
```

The MapCtrl controller has a method that loads the map and other methods that I use for other user function (related to the map).

The problem: the first time the user loads the page , Angularjs application is loaded before the "map" node has been created by the DOM and the map doesn't load.

How can I solve it?

Thank you in advance;

Luca

Comment: make a directive for the map

Comment: Do you mean for the main map controller?

Comment: I mean instead of manipulating DOM in a controller, I would write a directive which are the recommended place to work with DOM, and this will make sure that your elements that you depend on already exist.